# log4j2 CustomAppender to rename the completed file and to append some data string

Tags: java, log4j2

As I've asked on an another topic

- Lets name the currently written file: current, and to the completed one: previous. The current is "logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log" i.e. "logs/app-09-18-2017.log". The previous is "logs/app-Completed235015-09-18-2017.log". The "Completed_235015" means that the file definitely was completed on this certain time: 23:50:15. Is it possible to configure ? Or perhaps create a plugin and to implement it in Java, though I'm not sure how to do it ... :)

I'm trying to do achieve something not quite standard from the log4j2 capabilities while using the RollingFile and TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy options.

After completion of the currently written file and before a new one is created, I would like to insert the Completed_HHmmss timestamp to the completed filename and append to it the following file's description.
Since these actions may require some Java code activation, I suppose that a CustomAppender will be required.

Thanks

Comment: you can use a placeholder to replace timestamp into the string which represents the filePattern

Comment: What do you mean by place holder ?
The Completed_HHmmsd timestamp is one of the application requirements, as well as the text that must be appended to the completed file.
Currently all the application threads outputs are handled by the designated Java class, which became too complicated.
This is the reason that I'm looking for a different solution based on log4j2.

Comment: Perhaps a solution might be as follows: using the regular RollingFileAppender while the current file is written, and when it's  completed a CustomAppender is activated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a following solution could be implemented:

While the current file is updated, a regular RollingFileAppender is used, and upon the completion some CustomAppender will be activated. This CustomAppender will insert the Completed_MMddyyyy string into the file's name and will append the subsequent file's description to the completed file.

Is it feasible ?
How should I define and implement such a CustomAppender ?

Thanks